# JAX-RS/jersey, Spring: Managing child resources lifecycle

Tags: java, spring, rest, jax-rs

I'm developing a RESTful service using JAX-RS/Jersey and Spring. I have two resources: Category and Item. Item is a child of Category.
So,
***GET rest/category*** would return a list of Categories.
***GET rest/category/123*** would return a Category with id = 123.
***GET rest/category/123/item*** would return a list of Items included in Category with id = 123.

Here are my resource classes:

```
@Controller
@Path(value = "category")
public class CategoryResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<CategoryEntity> getAllCategories() {
        return repo.findAll();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{id:\\d+}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public CategoryEntity getCategory(@PathParam("id") long id) {
        return repo.findOne(id);
    }

    @Path("{id:\\d+}/item")
    public ItemResource getItem(@PathParam("id") long id) {
        return new ItemResource(id);
    }


    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepository repo;    
}



public class ItemResource {

    public ItemResource(@PathParam("id") long categoryId) {
        this.category = repoCategory.findOne(categoryId);
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<ItemEntity> getAllItems() {
        return repoItem.findByCategory(this.category);
    }


    private CategoryEntity category;    

    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepository repoCategory; 

    @Autowired
    private ItemRepository repoItem; 

}
```

In this example every time ***GET rest/category/123/item*** is sent a new instance of ItemResource will be created, even if Category id is the same each time. So each time ItemResource will be constructed, the database will be queried:

```
this.category = repoCategory.findOne(categoryId);
```

Is it possible to prevent this by keeping instances of ItemResource alive throughout a session, so that they are reused whenever Items from a specific Category are requested more than once? Or is it generally a bad idea?

Comment: What is your `ItemResource`?

Comment: @Cássio Mazzochi Molin I'm sorry, I have mixed things up a bit. I have now rewritten my question in a more clear way.

Comment: But what are sub-resource locators then used for? I'm speaking about example 3.18 in this Jersey documentation: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html

Comment: I think I misread your question and didn't understand your problem.

Comment: Ok, thank you anyway.

Comment: `@PathParam`s should be propagated down to the sub-resource. Have you tried to add it to the sub-resource method instead? If you do this, then you can just use the same cached instance for _all_ requests, regardless of id (of course given the sub-resource class is stateless).

Comment: @peeskillet I think I got it. Thank you.